# How to show a message from PHP file to a twig file?

Tags: javascript, php, twig

I am trying to send a message form a `PHP`-file to a `twig`-file when a wrong login is returned. There is the first part of my code:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
if (isset($_POST['reg'])) {
    if ($_POST['pwd1'] === $_POST['pwd2']) {
      //do something
    } else {
        echo ("<script>location.href = $twig->render('register.twig', array('theMessage' => 'Wrong password!'));</script>");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo $twig->render('register.twig');
}
```

and in `twig`-file:

```
{% if theMessage %}
  {{ theMessage }}
{% endif %}
```

When I run my code I am getting the page not good rendered as the first time. I am thinking maybe the method `render()` is not called or the `script` is not good written. Any help or suggestions to achieve this is very appreciate.

Comment: If you are using symfony, firt try "official" way of rendering twig templates: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: I am not using `synfony`. Just `PHP` and `twig`. I am just trying to pass a message from PHP file to my twig-file such I can read why for eksempel I cannot log in.

Comment: Just drop the `window.location` part and echo the `HTML` returned by `twig`?

Comment: `@DarkBee` I tried this solution like that: ` echo $twig->render('register.twig', array('theMessage' => 'Wrong password!'));`, but nothing is happened in `HTML`!

Comment: Should definitely work, are you running twig in debug mode? Perhaps there is an error in your twig file